# Android widgets crashing in Expo project

Tags: android, kotlin, expo, widget, eas

I've built an android widget in Android Studio using kotlin, it also has a config where you change some inputs when you launch it and then make an api call with those selected values

The project works perfectly in Android Studio locally, the problem is that i need to integrate it in an expo react native project.

I did that followind this example here: https://github.com/gaishimo/eas-widget-example

The build in production was successfull, the problem is that when i try to add the widget to the homescreen of an android home, it crashes and throws an error that i caught in LogCat:

Unable to send back result
android.app.PendingIntent$CanceledException

Which i think is related to the Widget Config Activity class, which is this one:

```
    package com.example.widgettest

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class WidgetConfigActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_widget_config)

        // Find the widget id from the intent.
        val intent = intent
        val extras = intent.extras
        if (extras != null) {
            appWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
            )
        }

        // If this activity was started with an invalid appWidgetId, finish with an error.
        if (appWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish()
            return
        }

        val currentBlockchain = loadBlockchainPref(this, appWidgetId)
        val currentTimeframe = loadTimeframePref(this, appWidgetId)
        val currentReport = loadReportPref(this, appWidgetId)

        val reportSpinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.report_spinner)
        val initialReportOptions = getInitialReportOptions().toMutableList()
        val reportAdapter = ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
            this,
            R.layout.spinner_item,
            initialReportOptions
        )

        val timeframeSpinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.timeframe_spinner)
        val timeframeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.timeframe_array,
            R.layout.spinner_item
        )

        val blockchainSpinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.blockchain_spinner)
        val blockchainAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.blockchain_array,
            R.layout.spinner_item
        )

        reportAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)
        reportSpinner.adapter = reportAdapter

        blockchainAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)
        blockchainSpinner.adapter = blockchainAdapter

        timeframeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)
        timeframeSpinner.adapter = timeframeAdapter

        fun updateReportSpinnerOptions(blockchain: String, adapter: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>) {
            val reportOptions = when (blockchain) {
                "ETH" -> resources.getTextArray(R.array.reports_array_2).toList()
                "POLYGON" -> resources.getTextArray(R.array.reports_array_2).toList()
                "BNB" -> resources.getTextArray(R.array.reports_array_2).toList()
                else -> resources.getTextArray(R.array.reports_array).toList()
            }

            adapter.clear()
            adapter.addAll(reportOptions)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        blockchainSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val selectedBlockchain = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                updateReportSpinnerOptions(selectedBlockchain, reportAdapter)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                updateReportSpinnerOptions("SOL", reportAdapter)
            }
        }

        val timeframeArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.timeframe_array)
        val currentPosTimeframe = timeframeArray.indexOf(currentTimeframe)
        if (currentPosTimeframe >= 0) {
            timeframeSpinner.setSelection(currentPosTimeframe)
        }

        val reportArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.reports_array)
        val currentPosReport = reportArray.indexOf(currentReport)
        if (currentPosReport >= 0) {
            reportSpinner.setSelection(currentPosReport)
        }

        val blockchainArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.blockchain_array)
        val currentPos = blockchainArray.indexOf(currentBlockchain)
        if (currentPos >= 0) {
            blockchainSpinner.setSelection(currentPos)
        }

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.confirm_button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val selectedBlockchain = blockchainSpinner.selectedItem.toString()
            val selectedTimeframe = timeframeSpinner.selectedItem.toString()
            val selectedReport = reportSpinner.selectedItem.toString()

            saveTimeframePref(this, appWidgetId, selectedTimeframe)
            saveBlockchainPref(this, appWidgetId, selectedBlockchain)
            saveReportPref(this, appWidgetId, selectedReport)

            // Update the widget
            val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this)
            val appWidgetInfo = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId)
            val provider = appWidgetInfo.provider

            val intentUpdate = Intent(this, MyAppWidgetProvider::class.java).apply {
                action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
                putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, intArrayOf(appWidgetId))
            }

            when (provider.className) {
                SmallWidgetProvider::class.java.name -> intentUpdate.component = ComponentName(this, SmallWidgetProvider::class.java)
                MediumWidgetProvider::class.java.name -> intentUpdate.component = ComponentName(this, MediumWidgetProvider::class.java)
                LargeWidgetProvider::class.java.name -> intentUpdate.component = ComponentName(this, LargeWidgetProvider::class.java)
                CollectionsSmallWidgetProvider::class.java.name -> intentUpdate.component = ComponentName(this, CollectionsSmallWidgetProvider::class.java)
                CollectionsMediumWidgetProvider::class.java.name -> intentUpdate.component = ComponentName(this, CollectionsMediumWidgetProvider::class.java)
                CollectionsLargeWidgetProvider::class.java.name -> intentUpdate.component = ComponentName(this, CollectionsLargeWidgetProvider::class.java)
                // Add other cases as necessary
            }

            sendBroadcast(intentUpdate)

            // Return the result to the widget
            val resultValue = Intent().apply {
                putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            }
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue)

            val startMain = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).apply {
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            }
            startActivity(startMain)
            finish()

        }
    }

    private fun getInitialReportOptions(): List<CharSequence> {
        return resources.getTextArray(R.array.reports_array).toList()
    }

    companion object {
        fun saveBlockchainPref(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int, text: String) {
            val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("widget_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = prefs.edit()
            editor.putString("blockchain_$appWidgetId", text)
            editor.apply()
        }

        fun saveTimeframePref(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int, text: String) {
            val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("widget_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = prefs.edit()
            editor.putString("timeframe_$appWidgetId", text)
            editor.apply()
        }

        fun saveReportPref(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int, text: String) {
            val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("widget_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = prefs.edit()
            editor.putString("report_$appWidgetId", text)
            editor.apply()
        }

        fun loadBlockchainPref(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int): String {
            val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("widget_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            return prefs.getString("blockchain_$appWidgetId", "SOL") ?: "SOL"
        }

        fun loadReportPref(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int): String {
            val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("widget_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            return prefs.getString("report_$appWidgetId", "volumes") ?: "volumes"
        }

        fun loadTimeframePref(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int): String {
            val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("widget_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            return prefs.getString("timeframe_$appWidgetId", "24h") ?: "24h"
        }
    }
```

And then this is the class I use the widget config in:

```
abstract class MyAppWidgetProvider: AppWidgetProvider() {
@Override
override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray?
) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
    // Perform widget update logic here
    appWidgetIds?.forEach { appWidgetId ->
        // Launch a coroutine for asynchronous operation
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val selectedBlockchain = WidgetConfigActivity.loadBlockchainPref(context, appWidgetId)
                val selectedTimeframe = WidgetConfigActivity.loadTimeframePref(context, appWidgetId)
                val selectedReport = WidgetConfigActivity.loadReportPref(context, appWidgetId)

                val formattedReport = formatMarketplacesReport(selectedReport)
                val formattedTimeframe = formatTimeframe(selectedTimeframe)
                val responseData = fetchSnapshot(
                    selectedBlockchain,
                    createQuery(formattedReport.report, "${formattedReport?.key}_${formattedTimeframe}"),
                    "${formattedReport?.key}_${formattedTimeframe}"
                )

                // Parse the response
                val volumesSnapshot = parseMarketplacesResponse(responseData, formattedTimeframe, formattedReport)
                val newVolumesSnapshot = mutableListOf<MarketplaceData>()
                val volumeMarketplacesTimeframe = getVolumeSnapshotData(volumesSnapshot, "${formattedReport?.key}_${formattedTimeframe}")

                volumeMarketplacesTimeframe?.marketplaces?.sortedByDescending { it?.amountSol }?.take(7)?.forEach { vol ->
                    try {
                        val marketplaceURL = getMarketplaceLogo(vol.marketplace)
                        val bitmap = downloadImage(marketplaceURL)

                        newVolumesSnapshot.add(vol.copy(imageBitmap = bitmap))
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        // Handle any exceptions, e.g., network errors, etc.
                        Log.e("WidgetUpdateService", "Error downloading image", e)
                    }
                }
                // Update the widget with the parsed data
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    updateAppWidget(
                        context,
                        appWidgetManager,
                        appWidgetId,
                        TimeFrameData(
                            percentageDifference = volumeMarketplacesTimeframe?.percentageDifference ?: 0.00,
                            amountDollars = volumeMarketplacesTimeframe?.amountDollars ?: 0.00,
                            amountSol = volumeMarketplacesTimeframe?.amountSol ?: 0.00,
                            marketplaces = newVolumesSnapshot
                        ),
                        selectedBlockchain,
                        selectedTimeframe,
                        formattedReport.key,
                        selectedReport
                    )
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Handle exceptions
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun setupWidgetClick(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int, views: RemoteViews) {
    val intent = Intent(context, WidgetConfigActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
    }

    val pendingIntentFlags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    } else {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    }

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, pendingIntentFlags)
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update_blockchain, pendingIntent)
}

@Override
override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    super.onEnabled(context)

    // Launch a coroutine for asynchronous operation
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val formattedReport = formatMarketplacesReport("Volumes")
            // Fetch the GraphQL data
            val responseData = fetchSnapshot(
                "SOL",
                createQuery("volumesSnapshot", "vol_24h"),
                "vol_24h"
            )

            // Update all widget instances
            val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            val thisWidget = ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider::class.java)
            val appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget)

            val volumesSnapshot = parseMarketplacesResponse(responseData, "24h", formattedReport)
            val newVolumesSnapshot = mutableListOf<MarketplaceData>()
            val volumeMarketplacesTimeframe = getVolumeSnapshotData(volumesSnapshot, "vol_24h")

            volumeMarketplacesTimeframe?.marketplaces?.sortedByDescending { it?.amountSol }?.take(7)?.forEach { vol ->
                try {
                    val marketplaceURL = getMarketplaceLogo(vol.marketplace)
                    val bitmap = downloadImage(marketplaceURL)

                    newVolumesSnapshot.add(vol.copy(imageBitmap = bitmap))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    // Handle any exceptions, e.g., network errors, etc.
                    Log.e("WidgetUpdateService", "Error downloading image", e)
                }
            }

            appWidgetIds.forEach { appWidgetId ->
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    updateAppWidget(
                        context,
                        appWidgetManager,
                        appWidgetId,
                        TimeFrameData(
                            percentageDifference = volumeMarketplacesTimeframe?.percentageDifference ?: 0.00,
                            amountDollars = volumeMarketplacesTimeframe?.amountDollars ?: 0.00,
                            amountSol = volumeMarketplacesTimeframe?.amountSol ?: 0.00,
                            marketplaces = newVolumesSnapshot
                        ),
                        "SOL",
                        "24H",
                        formattedReport.key,
                        "Volumes"
                    )
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle exceptions
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

abstract fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int,
    volumesSnapshot: TimeFrameData,
    selectedBlockchain: String,
    selectedTimeframe: String,
    selectedReport: String,
    reportName: String
)
```

There is something wrong within the config class when it sets the widget ID, but i'm not sure what..